# What is the best way to listen to a lot of new albums I just bought?

Tags: rock, metal

I bought a lot of CD of the 60 to 80 decades to enrich my music library. Which is the best way to listen to all without go crazy? Im currently listening one album per week, but I find it a little boring.

Answer (score 2):

First I would say it depends on what albums you have.

Generally, I will disagree with @Tetsujin's answer with some albums that can't be mixed and randomize with other albums. I think of Pink Floyd's [*The Wall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wall), or the Beatles' [*Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sgt._Pepper%27s_Lonely_Hearts_Club_Band) albums that are often written as a whole and have to be listened straight in the order.

In another hand, I find it more difficult to listen albums like Robert Johnson's [*The Complete Recordings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Complete_Recordings_(Robert_Johnson_album)) in one time, so in this case I could use @Tetsujin's trick.

### Acurate listening

You can read the lyrics while you are listening, it will help you to concentrate on the words, the lead singer. The next time you listen the album, you can switch and concentrate your listening to another musician... in time you will have a good knowledge of their personal style.
If you have several albums of the same band, you could noticed how they evolved, if they switched members etc...

### Documentation listening

In a more casual way, you just listen the album while you are reading articles of the band, reviews of the album, pictures of the band. You will reinforce your knowledge of it.
You may find articles written the day of the first release... it's interesting to read what people thought of it before it became famous.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be too rigid.  If you really aren't enjoying an album after a couple listens, go on to another.  Or, pick a few from the same decade (or across decades), and listen to them in rotation.

Another thing that might help is learning more about the music --look up some information on the songs, the artist, and the album, to give it some context.  It can be hard to really appreciate songs from earlier decades without knowing the world they were created for.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rip.
2. Playlist.
3. Shuffle.
4. Enjoy.

Comment: i hope when you say shuffle you do not mean shuffle the tracks. Many albums are arranged specifically  for the tracks to be played in chronological order. Even if they were not meant to be played in order you could never get a sense of an album as a whole if you listened the tracks randomly dispersed among other albums tracks. IMO you should turn off all distractions, sit down and listen to the album  from start to finish without interruption. Then if you want, go back to a track to get a better understanding or appreciation of it. Or listen to it again start to finish. Bebs said it well

Comment: The OP just said he was getting crazy & bored. I thought this was a valid alternative.